# Better way to do whitelabelling with I18N?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I feel like I'm sort of abusing Rails I18N by doing this... is there a better way?

We're building an app that has I18N, so using the standard techniques as documented in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

We also want to brand the app per client, and I'm doing this by *overlaying* this on the localization.

E.g. I have this in `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    brand = request.subdomains.first || nil
    I18n.locale = [brand, params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale].compact.join('_')
  end

end
```

and then in `en.yml`:

```
en:
  home: "Home"
arc_en:
  home: "ARC 1-Click Home"
yata_en:
  home: "YATA Home"
```

It works, but this feels sort of kludgy and maybe I'll regret it down the road.  Is there a better way?

---

Okay, I've sort of run into an issue with this approach.  What I fully have in `application_controller.rb` is:

```
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = [brand, params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale].compact.join('_')
  end

  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => ((I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale) ? nil : I18n.locale) }
  end
```

and in `routes.rb` I do:

```
Oneclick::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /arc_en|arc_es|yata_en|yata_es/ do
    authenticated :user do
      root :to => 'home#index'
    end
    devise_for :users
    resources :users
    match '/' => 'home#index'
  end
  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

It works, but I'm not crazy about the URLs I'm getting.  For example, I might start at `http://arc.1click.local:3000/` in my dev environment (and it defaults to `:en` as specified in my `application.rb`), but then the sign-up link is `http://arc.1click.local:3000/arc_en/users/sign_up`.

I'd rather it be `http://arc.1click.local:3000/users/sign_up` (since it can get the brand `arc` from the domain name and `en` is the default locale) or I could even live with `http://arc.1click.local:3000/en/users/sign_up`.

Suggestions?

Comment: Piling on to the answers, this seems like an elegant solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

If your branding consists entirely of text changes, I think using the I18n facilities makes sense. Alternatively you could set up separate config files containing the different settings between your brands and use these config settings to change how your app appears / behaves. A combination of I18n and config files can also work. Not sure if it's the best way, but it's proven effective.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a locale is simplistically, a language + a cultural reference, a character set etc... so in that sense, this approach is totally valid.

To be a bit more consistent with the ISO flavor of locale definitions, the language code would appear first, followed by the regional identifier (eg. `pt-BR`), but in any case the idea of having a language + a DSL identifier seems perfectly legitimate to me (imagine `en-medical`, makes total sense).

There's a whole bunch of features from I18n that could come in handy like fallbacks and defaults which may help you to abstract the content from your application.

Apart from the potential maintenance burden that such a system might cause, this solution actually seems more elegant than kludgy.

Sorry, not really, a reply, just my 2c.